# Can't make Unity Launcher appear

Tags: unity, 12.10, taskbar, autohide

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and I want to make unity launcher to auto-hide but when it hides it doesn't appear again unless I press the start button. Should I reinstall unity through terminal? I don't have any updates and the fastest speed and sensivity didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it was related to the compability nvidia-current-updates (wich I installed before the upgrade to 12.10) with compiz.

I fixed it by installing the version 310.19 of the nvidia driver avaiable through this ppa (this is not the official supported version on ubuntu, but works pretty well):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

In order to get this fix to work, you may have to reboot after installing the ppa.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you refer to as Unity is "Launcher". And in the same window you set it to auto hide (*System Settings > Appearance > Behaviour*), you can set the **Reveal Sensitivity** to a higher value to make it show quicker when you hover.

And see if **Reveal Location** is set to *Left side* or *Left corner* as it defines which action triggers Launcher to show.

Comment: I have done tha. I have turned the sensivity of the launcher, the mose speed and the mouse sensivity to full but nothing happening.

Comment: What **Reveal Location** is set to?

Comment: left side. But it doesn't work.