# Launcher does not reappear after auto-hide

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t make Unity Launcher appear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218796/cant-make-unity-launcher-appear)

I am having trouble getting launcher to appear after auto-hide. I have tried adjusting the sensitivity, and have even reset the launcher with no luck.

When I turn on the auto-hide function, the only way to get the launcher to re-appear is to turn auto-hide off.

Does any one know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218796/cant-make-unity-launcher-appear) worked for me. However, you will have to reboot after doing the steps described there.

Hope it works for you!